# Failed to make bulk upsert using mongo

Tags: java, mongodb, bulk, upsert

I'm trying to do upsert using mongodb driver, here is a code:

```
BulkWriteOperation builder = coll.initializeUnorderedBulkOperation();
DBObject toDBObject;
for (T entity : entities) {
    toDBObject = morphia.toDBObject(entity);
    builder.find(toDBObject).upsert().replaceOne(toDBObject);
}
BulkWriteResult result = builder.execute();
```

where "entity" is morphia object. When I'm running the code first time (there are no entities in the DB, so all of the queries should be `insert`) it works fine and I see the entities in the database with generated `_id` field. Second run I'm changing some fields and trying to save changed entities and then I receive the folowing error from mongo:

```
E11000 duplicate key error collection: statistics.counters index: _id_ dup key: { : ObjectId('56adfbf43d801b870e63be29') }
```

what I forgot to configure in my example?

Comment: Why the .find first?  Can you just use .Upsert and skip the .find?

Comment: I took an example from mongodb manual:
https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.0/reference/method/Bulk.find.upsert/

Comment: Moreover there is no API for BulkWriteOperation.upsert()

Answer (score 1):

I don't know the structure of dbObject, but that bulk Upsert needs a valid query in order to work.

Let's say, for example, that you have a unique (_id) property called "id". A valid query would look like:

```
builder.find({id: toDBObject.id}).upsert().replaceOne(toDBObject);
```

This way, the engine can (a) find an object to update and then (b) update it (or, insert if the object wasn't found).  Of course, you need the Java syntax for find, but same rule applies: **make sure your .find will find something, then do an update.**

I believe (just a guess) that the way it's written now will find "all" docs and try to update the first one ... but the behavior you are describing suggests it's finding "no doc" and attempting an insert.